# Multiple Comparison of Different Indexes Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, indexing

New to Python/Pandas. Trying to iterate through a dataframe and check for duplicates. If a duplicate is found, compare the duplicates 'BeginTime' at index to 'BeginTime' at index + 1. If true, assign a new time to a different dataframe. When I run the code the first duplicate should produce a new time of 'Grab & Go' but I think my comparison statement isn't right. I get '1130' as a new time for the first duplicate.

```
import pandas as import pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [97330, 97330, 95232, 95232, 95232], 
                   'BeginTime': [1135, 1255, 1135, 1255, 1415]})


 Expected Output:
 ID             NewTime
 97330          Grab & Go
 95232          Grab & Go   





# iterate through df
for index, row in df.iterrows():

# check for duplicates in the ID field comparing index to index + 1        
    if df.loc[index, 'ID'] == df.shift(+1).loc[index, 'ID']

# if a duplciate, compare 'BeginTime' of index to 'BeginTime' of index + 1 of the duplicate, 
# if true assign a new time to a different df  
       
            if df.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1135 and df.shift(+1).loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1255:
                    print('Yes, a duplicate', dfnew['NewTime'] = 'Grab & Go')
            elif df.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1255:
                    print('Yes, a duplicate', dfnew['NewTime'] = '1130')
            else:
                    print('No, not a duplicate')
```

Comment: What is your expected output from these data?

Comment: I actually should have added a few more comparisons, so example is not the best. The output should be
ID    NewTime
97330   Grab & Go
95232   Grab & Go

Comment: Why have the loop at all? Just use shift

Comment: How would I check the dataframe without the loop? The full data set has 14,000+ entries that I need to check.